# Polite ways of request (asking for something) in Spanish

Tags: preguntas, cortesía

I am struggling with polite questions. I am going to meet with a conductor and would like to ask the following question in Spanish: ‘Would you happen to have any scores so that we be able to follow you during the rehearsals?’

I have come up with these variants:

> ¿Es posible que tenga unas partituras para que podamos lo seguir durante los ensayos?
>
> ¿Podrias darnos unas partituras para que podamos lo seguir durante los ensayos?

Are these valid or considered as non-standard?
How would you ask the question yourself?

Comment: In case of doubt (like in the first sentence, where you translate directly from English "Is it possible to have") just add "por favor". Regardless of if you grammar is 100% the listener will understand that you are trying to make a polite request in a language you are not proficient with, and not just a demand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are good approaches, but they do not sound properly. I think the main error is "lo seguir", in Spanish it would be "seguirlo". Note that the verb *[seguir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XT8l8aE)* is also used as an intransitive verb, so "seguirle" is also right.

Other issues:

- The first sentence starts with "es posible que", which does not sound quite right.
- The second sentence uses *tú* instead of *usted*.

In Spanish we use the courtesy conditional tense for these kind of expressions. So for me your two sentences would be something like this:

> ¿Sería posible disponer de partituras para que podamos seguirle durante los ensayos?
>
> ¿Podría usted darnos partituras para que podamos seguirle durante los ensayos?

Note that I have not got deep into every issue in your sentences. If you need further explanations, please ask new questions, one for each issue you need more detail for.

Comment: More latinamerican alternatives: ¿Tendría disponibles unas partituras para nosotros poderlo seguir durante los ensayos? ¿Podría darnos/prestarnos unas partituras para nosotros poderlo seguir durante los ensayos?